# How to read Pkcs#7 certificate chain from file/stream in C#?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, pkcs#7

I have two certificates that I saved to disk. One is a certificate with private key that I exported as a .pfx file, the other one is a certificate that I saved including its certificate chain as a PKCS#7 file ("certchain.p7b").

In C# I can now load the .pfx file with

```
  var cert = new X509Certificate2(myPfxFileStream);
```

(myPfxFileStream is a `FileStream` opened to the .pfx File for reading), however trying the same thing with the PKCs#7 Certificate fails in a `CryptoGraphicException` "Der Indexwert ist ungültig" which translates to "invalid index value".

I assume I have to parse PKCS#7 differently (it contains a chain, not a single certificate!), but how?

(Oh, by the way: Currently I have no passwords on those certficiates)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to use the [`SignedCms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.aspx) class in the [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6see7k14.aspx) namespace.

This blog entry will show you how to use the class:

link update 2021: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/enveloped-pkcs-7-signatures

original link: http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/02/27/539990.aspx

You basically will call the [`Decode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.decode.aspx) method, passing the bytes representing the PKCS file.

Comment: Right on the spot. Thank you!